# Footage feels "faster" when exporting from After Effects

Tags: premiere, after-effects, framerate

I'm editing a project with premiere, and using After Effects to edit some of the footage (color corrections, some masking etc').

All raw footage was captured with a Canon 550D, 1280*720 at 50fps.

My premiere sequences are defined to be 50fps, as well as my AE compositions. However, when exporting edited footage from AE as 50fps H264, the exported edited footage feels "faster", compared to the original footage, even though thee clips have the same length. The discrepancy is very noticeable.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Just check that your footage has been _interpreted_ correctly in AE. Else a short snippet from before and after AE would be helpful.

Comment: Also take a look at the frame blur settings. If Premiere has frame blurring turned on and After Effects does not, this might change the perceived speed.

Comment: I will check on those, Thanks! What site can I use to upload the clips for you to view?

Comment: Dropbox or the ilk like WeTransfer should do.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem!

So let me explain the answer :

After effects imports your video at the wrong frame rate, so to fix it follow these steps :

1. Open the Project panel (by default on the left of your screen)
2. Right click on your footage and go to Interpret Footage -> Main... as shown below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JehOz.png]

- In the screen that opens up input the desired framerate (15fps in this case) in the textbox next to Conform to framerate. Press OK.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Yy0.png]

- Now After Effects should know that the footage is 15fps.

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to his problem (could be). But here is the original answer: [http://avp.stackexchange.com/a/6991/2178](http://avp.stackexchange.com/a/6991/2178)

Comment: Bart, thats indeed the answer i copied, i was a question I asked, and i thought I'd share it with him, so he can continue on what he's working on

Comment: It is a good idea to include a link to the answer if you are going to copy it.